# Simpy 4, starting multiple processes at the same time

Tags: python, simpy

I'm using Simpy 4, and can't figure out how to schedule multiple events for the same time.

For example, let's say there are 3 cars at a starting line, and I want them to all start at the same time. As an example, the code below doesn't work as I want because each 'move' happens one after the other, and not at the same time.

```
import simpy
from itertools import cycle

class Dispatch():
    def __init__(self, env, cars):
        self.cars = cars
        self.action = env.process(self.run())
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            for car in self.cars:
                yield env.process(car.move())
            
class Car():
    def __init__(self, env, name, initial_location):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.location = initial_location
        self.path = iter(cycle(["A", "B", "C", "B"]))
    
    def move(self):
        yield env.timeout(1)
        self.location = next(self.path)
        print("{} is now at position {}, at time: {}".format(self.name, self.location, env.now))
        
env = simpy.Environment()
carA = Car(env, "carA", "A")
carB = Car(env, "carB", "A")
carC = Car(env, "carC", "A")
dispatcher = Dispatch(env, [carA,carB,carC])
env.run(until=20)
```

Now because each car is started sequentially, this gives the result:

```
carA is now at position A, at time: 1
carB is now at position A, at time: 2
carC is now at position A, at time: 3
carA is now at position B, at time: 4
carB is now at position B, at time: 5
carC is now at position B, at time: 6
carA is now at position C, at time: 7
carB is now at position C, at time: 8
carC is now at position C, at time: 9
```

But what I want is:

```
carA is now at position A, at time: 1
carB is now at position A, at time: 1
carC is now at position A, at time: 1
carA is now at position B, at time: 2
carB is now at position B, at time: 2
carC is now at position B, at time: 2
carA is now at position C, at time: 3
carB is now at position C, at time: 3
carC is now at position C, at time: 3
```

So I guess I'm looking for a way to re-write the for loop.

In the end, there will be multiple cars (like in the example above), and I want to control each car separately. But I guess as a starting point, it would be good to know how to add each car event to the event list so they start at the same time.

Any help? Thanks :)

Best regards

EDIT

Ok, I won't put this down as an answer yet, because I don't exactly understand it. But I have the result I want. I create multiple Dispatch objects, and run each one separately. Unless someone else can clearly explain this, I'll wait until I have figured it out and then post an answer.

```
class Dispatch():
    def __init__(self, env, car):
        self.car = car
        self.action = env.process(self.run())
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            yield env.process(self.car.moveto())
            
class Car():
    def __init__(self, env, name, initial_location):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.location = initial_location
        self.path = cycle(["A", "B", "C", "B"])
    
    def moveto(self):
        if self.name == "carA":
            yield env.timeout(1)
        elif self.name == "carB":
            yield env.timeout(4)
        self.location = next(self.path)
        print("{} is now at node: {}, at time: {}".format(self.name, self.location, env.now))
        
env = simpy.Environment()
carA = Car(env, "carA", "A")
carB = Car(env, "carB", "A")
cars = [carA, carB]

for car in cars:
    Dispatch(env, car)

env.run(until=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fist code was almost there

The real issue is this line in your run method of your Dispatcher.

```
yield env.process(car.move())
```

you need to drop the yield

the yield causes you code to wait until the car.move() finishes before looping and starting the next car.

changing your code to

```
env.process(car.move())
```

This will run the car_move() process asynchronously

The other thing I did was move the movement down to the cars.  Having each car with its own timeout gives you options, such as interrupting one car for a mechanical failure.  You can also add a parameter to the car class to give each car a different speed

see the code below

```
import simpy
from itertools import cycle

class Dispatch():
    def __init__(self, env, cars, startTime=0):
        self.env = env
        self.cars = cars
        self.action = env.process(self.run(startTime))
    
    def run(self,startTime):
        # wait for start of race 
        yield self.env.timeout(startTime)
        for car in self.cars:
                # no yield here
                env.process(car.move())
            
class Car():
    def __init__(self, env, name, initial_location):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.location = initial_location
        self.path = iter(cycle(["A", "B", "C", "B"]))
    
    def move(self):
        # let each car move itself, more like a real car
        while True:
            print("{} is now at position {}, at time: {}".format(self.name, self.location, env.now))
            yield env.timeout(1)
            self.location = next(self.path)
        
env = simpy.Environment()
carA = Car(env, "carA", "A")
carB = Car(env, "carB", "A")
carC = Car(env, "carC", "A")
dispatcher = Dispatch(env, [carA,carB,carC])
env.run(until=20)
```

Comment: This works while following philosophy of simpy stated in [the document](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/time_and_scheduling.html#time-and-scheduling). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `threading` to run cars at the same time:

```
import time
import threading
from itertools import cycle

CARS = ['carA', 'carB', 'carC']
POS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = iter(cycle(POS))
        self.time = 1

    def run(self):
        while self.time < 5:
            pos = next(self.pos)
            print(f'{self.name} is now at position {pos}, at time: {self.time}')
            self.time += 1
            time.sleep(1)

[threading.Thread(target=Car(car).run).start() for car in CARS]
```

Output:

```
carA is now at position A, at time: 1
carB is now at position A, at time: 1
carC is now at position A, at time: 1
carB is now at position B, at time: 2
carC is now at position B, at time: 2
carA is now at position B, at time: 2
carB is now at position C, at time: 3
carA is now at position C, at time: 3
carC is now at position C, at time: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of doing it that way. But I'm wondering how to schedule multiple events for for the same time in the simpy event queue.

Comment: What do you mean by `events`?

Comment: I'm using the Simpy library, which is a discrete event simulator. Basically you can schedule events in an event stack. I was looking for a way to add multiple events to trigger at the same time in the stack. I found out how to do it (I edited my first post), but I'm still wrapping my head around how it works exactly.